# work on parent screen at the same time with colorbox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

I am new to colorbox and jquery

can some one help me with the coding of colorbox setup which will allow working on parent screen without closing the colorbox popup.

my coding for colorbox popup is

```
$.colorbox({ width: '900px', opacity:'0', height: '90%', iframe: true, open: true, overlayClose: false, escKey: false, href: '/e4/communication/send-communication.aspx?communicationtemplateid=' + id + '&applicationid=' + appids.slice(0, 19).toString() + '&istb=1&TB_iframe=true' });
            }
```

The popup position is fixed. I cant drag or move it

The css for the colorbox is

```
#cboxOverlay,#cboxWrapper,#colorbox{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:9999;overflow:hidden}
#cboxOverlay{position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%}
#cboxBottomLeft,#cboxMiddleLeft{clear:left}
#cboxContent{position:relative}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto}
#cboxTitle{margin:0}
#cboxLoadingGraphic,#cboxLoadingOverlay{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%}
#cboxClose,#cboxNext,#cboxPrevious,#cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer}
.cboxPhoto{float:left;margin:auto;border:0;display:block}
.cboxIframe{width:100%;height:100%;display:block;border:0}
#cboxOverlay{background:#777}
#cboxContent{margin-top:20px}
#cboxError{padding:50px;border:1px solid #ccc}
#cboxLoadedContent{background:#fff}
#cboxTitle{position:absolute;top:-20px;left:0;color:#ccc}
#cboxCurrent{position:absolute;top:-20px;right:0;color:#ccc;display:none!important}
#cboxSlideshow{position:absolute;top:-20px;right:90px;color:#fff}
#cboxPrevious{position:absolute;top:50%;left:5px;margin-top:-32px;background:url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat top left;width:28px;height:65px;text-indent:-9999px;display:none!important}
#cboxPrevious.hover{background-position:bottom left}
#cboxNext{position:absolute;top:50%;right:5px;margin-top:-32px;background:url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat top right;width:28px;height:65px;text-indent:-9999px;display:none!important}
#cboxNext.hover{background-position:bottom right}
#cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#000}
#cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center}
#cboxClose{position:absolute;top:5px;right:5px;display:block;background:url(../images/controls.png) no-repeat top center;width:38px;height:19px;text-indent:-9999px;z-index:-1}
#cboxClose.hover{background-position:bottom center}
#newPriv,#newTerm{display:none}
#exPriv,#exTerm{padding:10px;border:1px solid #dedede}
```

I will appreciate your help

Comment: your requirement isn't clear can you make it more clear change your question so we can understand more & help you

Comment: Actually I've been asked to look after a system which has been developed by another developer. In the system he used colorbox to open popup page. When The popups are opened it disables the parent screen. i.e once the popup is open u cant do any work in the parent screen. which is not helpful always. sometimes the user wants both screen open & working on both screen at the same time. e.g; the help page is opened in a popup page. and in the current system the user cant working on parent screen while looking at the popup screen at the same time. they have to close the help screen and then work.

Comment: In my question i have given the codes which has been created by the previous developer. The top first line of code lies on the parent screen. I guess that handles the behavior of popup. and css for popup. can you suggest any code that will allow clicking on the parent screen without closing the popup screen.